# How do i manage workspace.xml in Intellij with git

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I started a new project with my team. We are using **Intellij + Java + git** for developing the software.

The problem I have is that I made a `.gitignore` file for git auto-generated by [gitignore.io](http://www.gitignore.io). The file ignores the `workspace.xml` and the `Project.iml` files in my Project, which is good, because they cause merging conflicts later.

The thing is when I push the project on [bitbucket.org](http://www.bitbucket.org) and my collegues want to clone it so they can work on it, they have no `workspace.xml`. So Intellij can't open it up as a project.

Is there any way they can generate the missing Files or any Import option to make it a project again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

workspace.xml is not required for opening an IntelliJ IDEA project. On the other hand, the .iml file is a required part of the project and needs to be shared in the version control system if you want to share your project with colleagues.

Comment: Ok, so i just need to add the .iml file in to the VCS to make it a Intellij Project?

Comment: You need to add the .iml file and the contents of the .idea directory excluding workspace.xml and tasks.xml.

Comment: @yole I think the annoyance here if you don't version workspace.xml is that you lose Run Configurations. If your project has a lot of separate modules that execute independently or you have various different test configurations, along with any JVM parameters or whatever they contain, all that stuff stays local. Kind of annoying if you also use Git to sync multiple environments. I wish they'd pull that stuff out of that file. Or maybe I should say "y'all" since I see your profile "IDEA Product Manager". :)

Comment: @Manius, when you make a new Run Configuration, there's a checkbox in the upper right corner that let's you store the configuration as a Project File (says something like that). If you do that it will be stored outside of `workspace.xml` and shared with other people in the project via git.

Comment: Oh yeah I think I forgot about that option, I'll have to give that a try.